# Why is my neural network cost function increasing despite giving correct predictions?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm creating a neural network in python to recognize handwritten numbers. I'm pretty sure my feedforward, backpropagation, and gradient descent are correct since my program has a training accuracy of around 90%. I'm confident that it's working properly because I physically pulled out a couple random testing example images and compared it with the prediction and they were all correct.

However, plotting cost function J against iteration, I'm getting very weird results. Sometimes it decreases in a weird way and sometimes it increases, depending on what I chose for my regularization factor lambda. Here's an example plot:

[image: Iterations vs Cost function J]

I suspect that the mistake is how I coded the cost function, although I cannot spot it. Here is the function:

```
def J2(y_target, y_pred, theta1, theta2, lamb):
 """
 Args:
    y_target np.array(n_samples,10): One-hot target class
    y_pred np.array(n_samples,10): Predicted class likelihoods
    [...]
 """
 m = y_target.shape[1]

 cost = np.multiply(y_target, np.log(y_pred)) + np.multiply((1-y_target),np.log(1-y_pred))
 cost = np.sum(cost)
 cost = (-1/m)*cost

 reg = np.sum(np.square(theta1)) + np.sum(np.square(theta2))
 reg = (lamb/2*m)*reg

 J = cost + reg
return J
```

Here is how I did forward and backward propagation:

```
def forward_prop2(X, theta1, theta2):
   #forward propagation
   #X is a 'm by n' matrix
     #m = number of examples
     #n = number of features 
   a1 = np.transpose(X)

   z2 = np.matmul(theta1, a1)
   a2 = sigmoid(z2)
   a2 = np.append(np.ones((1,a2.shape[1])),a2,axis=0)

   z3 = np.matmul(theta2, a2)
   a3 = sigmoid(z3)

return a1, a2, a3

def backward_prop2(y_vectors, a1, a2, a3, theta1, theta2, lamb):
   #backward propagation
   #y_vectors is vectors of results (see notes for clarification)
   #outputs gradiat arrays for theta1 and theta2

   m = y_vectors.shape[1]

   delta3 = a3 - y_vectors

   delta2_matmul_term = np.matmul(np.transpose(theta2),delta3)
   delta2_dot_term = np.multiply(a2, np.ones(a2.shape)-a2)
   delta2 = np.multiply(delta2_matmul_term,delta2_dot_term)

   triangle2 = np.matmul(delta3, np.transpose(a2))

   triangle1 = np.matmul(delta2[1:,:],np.transpose(a1))

   reg2 = np.zeros((theta2.shape[0],1))
   reg2 = np.append(reg2,theta2[:,1:],axis=1)

   grad2 = (1/m)*triangle2 + lamb*reg2

   reg1 = np.zeros((theta1.shape[0],1))
   reg1 = np.append(reg1,theta1[:,1:],axis=1)

   grad1 = (1/m)*triangle1 + lamb*reg1

return grad1, grad2
```

And then finally I run this for loop:

```
iterations = 1000
alpha = 1
lamb = 0
J = []
for i in range (0, iterations):
    a1, a2, a3 = nn.forward_prop2(X_train, theta1, theta2)
    grad1, grad2 = nn.backward_prop2(y_vectors_train, a1, a2, a3, theta1, theta2, lamb)
    theta1 ,theta2 = nn.grad_des(theta1, theta2, grad1, grad2, alpha)
    J.append(nn.J2(y_vectors_train, a3, theta1, theta2, lamb))

plt.plot(J)
plt.xlabel('Iterations')
plt.ylabel('J')
plt.show()
```

Edit:
Here's the plot after making lambda very small, i.e. 0.0000000001:
[image: Making lambda very small]

It still looks a bit off to me.

Comment: Is this the validation loss or the training loss?

Comment: You should probably check the values of theta1 and theta2, I'm guessing they are very high. This leads to high values for `reg` which makes J increase. Although how this model actually learns is beyond me ...

Comment: I think it isn't a mistake in theta1 and theta 2 because the algorithm actually works in giving correct predictions. The only problem is with displaying the cost function. The method to learn is this: https://medium.com/secure-and-private-ai-math-blogging-competition/https-medium-com-fadymorris-understanding-vectorized-implementation-of-neural-networks-dae4115ca185. @Avandale

Comment: Not sure what these terms mean, I'm quite new. @MushfiratMohaimin

Comment: I'm not saying that these terms have mistakes, I'm saying that their value is high (which is not necessarily a bad thing). Try lowering your value of `lambda`, (by like... a lot), and your graph should be ok. 
One more question, how are you doing back-propagation ? could you show us your full code ?

Comment: @Avandale Thanks for the suggestion with lowering lambda. Setting lambda to 0.000000001 makes the cost function decrease, but not in a way that I expected (I've edited the question with a new picture of the iteration vs J plot). Also, I've updated the question with the forward and backward propagation.

Answer (score 0):

I agree, the issue seems to be linked with theta1,2, although it also seems unclear to me how the model learns if what you're plotting is the training accuracy.

Also, you mention `y_vectors` is an 'm by 10' array, yet assign `m = y_vectors.shape[1]`. It seems like you should write `m = y_vectors.shape[0]`.

P.s.: My post is more of a comment, but I can't comment yet.

Comment: OP is plotting the cost function, not the training accuracy - although the 2 should be correlated

Comment: Sorry, I've made a typo in my question. I've rechecked my code and it's actually a '10 by m' array.